# Hashing function (General Theory)

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I've been looking an answer for a while and I was wondering if anyone knows how to define explicitly (from scratch) a hash function in C#. I understand that there are pre-defined data structures that have List abilities, but I'm trying to understand the underlying structures of these objects.

Can anyone help with this? For example, if you have two arrays, how would you be able to create a hash table from this?

Answer (score 10):

The Wikipedia articles on [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are ridiculously good. You could also check out [Volume 3 of TAOCP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896850). Lastly, a peek in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) at [System.Collections.Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) would probably be an edifying experience.

If you have more specific questions, we can probably provide more detailed insight.

Comment: thanks for the links above. I'll go through them. I also added an additional part to the question, mainly if you have two arrays, how would you be able to create a hash table with them?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to hash two arrays, it sort of depends on what kind of data the arrays are holding. For example, if you mean to be hashing arrays of strings you'll need an extra step to encode the strings and integers before hashing them because what you'll essentially need is to convert your input into an index for your hash table, given a hash function. Of course, when you are 'converting your input' you have to solve the problem of collisions among your keys. In other words, you have to try and minimize the number of keys that hash to the same value, which is why Number Theory (specifically, the use of prime numbers) becomes particularly useful.

I assume that when you ask to know how to 'create a hash table' from two arrays you mean for the data in the two arrays to be the keys of the table. In that case, I can't see why you would need to refer to two arrays instead of a bigger array that contains the elements of the two arrays unless you are dealing with a statically-typed programming language and the two arrays can have different types. In this case, you will need to come up with a scheme to convert the elements into integers. If you want to convert a string s of length n where s[i] is the ith character in the string (referring to its ASCII value) into an integer, for example, you can look at how  [Java's hashCode() function does the job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()#The_java.lang.String_hash_function) It essentially evaluates a polynomial with a prime base so as to avoid having different strings hash to the same integer. And the reason why the base is 31, other than the fact that it is prime, is because multiplying by 31 is close to a power of 2 so 31 can be done efficiently mostly with bit-shifting.

Once you have all your elements in the form of integers, you get to the real meat of the problem. There are basic tricks from which we can make elaborate combinations of, provided that the components of the combinations are relatively prime with one another so that we can scale to the entire hash table. Two of the basic methods are **the division method** and **the multiplication method**. These methods on their own, especially the division method, are insufficient because someone could eventually determine the function that hashed your keys. I would try to explain common ways of constructing hash functions, but I probably wouldn't explain them nearly as well as [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844). On the other hand, I can give you a list of properties to satisfy:

- You should minimize collisions
- Your function should be able to hash a key to any slot
  (so as to not violate
  **simple uniform hashing**
  )
- Your function should be hard to reverse-engineer

Bear in mind that in order to satisfy that last property typically some component(s) of the hash function should at least cause the slots they map the keys to to appear random. Due to this constraint we will still have a non-zero probability of having a collision, so your next problem to solve would be **collision resolution**.